# Delete row in text file

Tags: groovy

I'm reading a text file in Groovy:

```
new File(testprojectDir + '/Testdata///' + filename).withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
def line
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        log.info "${line}"
    }
}
```

The text file generates as follows:
123
456
789

My problem Is that I'd like to remove the line I've just red.

Example: 123 will be deleteted after it's been red.

And continue to next row, read that line and remove that line (save the same text file) until the file no longer has rows, that means that the text file is empty (every line is deleted)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an output file.

```
def ofile = new File(outputFile)
new File(testprojectDir + '/Testdata///' + filename).withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    def line
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null  && !line.contains("text i don't want")) {
        log.info "${line}"
        ofile.append(line)
    }
}
```

If you want to do it in-place:

```
def fileA = new File("src/file.txt")
List data = fileA.readLines()

fileA.text = ''

data.each { line ->
    if (!line.contains("b")) {
        log.info "${line}"
        fileA.append(line) + "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok - so I can't save to the same file? Do I have to create a new file?

Comment: You can truncate the file with `filename.text = ''` after you read all the lines ( with readLines() ), and then append the lines to it minus what you want to omit. Data will be lost if something goes wrong. File size will also matter.

Comment: Thanks for your updated solution @ou_ryperd Your solution works if I'm looking for the letter "b" but it won't delete the row containing "123" that's just been read?

Comment: I gave you a working example. It's up to you to get it working on your data.

Comment: One more question @ou_ryperd - If I only wants to read the first line in mentioned file? How do I achive that? Tried with List data = fileA.readLines().get(1)

Comment: The first line will be in the variable `line[0]`

Comment: Sorry @ou_ryperd I mean the first row in the file? If I only want to delete the first row in the fil?

Comment: If line is not line[0] write to file.

Comment: I tried, but all content in file was deleted: if (!line[0]). I'd like to: Only delete first row every time the script runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213837/discussion-between-ou-ryperd-and-user3624378).